# Jquery change div contents on dropdown's change()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that this problem might be easy to solve, but I was unable to find a working answer. I want to change div contents depending on dropdown selection change. The contents come as an Ajax response from server:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.iterationDropdown').change(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    $.ajax({
        url: pathname + "get_tasks/",
        type: "post",
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
        data: $(".iterationDropdownForm").serialize(),
        success: function(responseData) {
            $.each(responseData, function(key, value){
                $(".tasks").html("<p><a href =" + pathname + "task/" + value[1] + ">Google</a></p>")
            })
        }
    })
});
```

});

When I am using `.html()`, only the first value from Json response is inserted into div (I think because of the loop). And when I use `.append()`, the div is appended with extra Json data when I select another option from dropdown menu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After success before iterating json remove div's previous html and then append new html like this:

```
success: function(responseData) {

    $(".tasks").html(""); // all html will be removed from the div

    $.each(responseData, function(key, value){

    $(".tasks").append("<p><a href =" + pathname + "task/" + value[1] + ">Google</a></p>")

    })
}
```

Comment: That works like a charm, thanks :) I spent like 3 hours figuring out what to do :/ thanks :/